# Algebraic fraction equality with 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm facing the following problem:

$$\frac{a}{(6x-1)} - \frac{1}{(3x+1)} = \frac{b}{(6x-1)(3x+1)}$$

$$\frac{a}{6x-1}-\frac{1}{3x+1}=\frac{3ax+a-6x+1}{\left(6x-1\right)\left(3x+1\right)}$$
where a and b are constants. Find the values of a and b.

I'm solid on the algebraic manipulation but can't get my head around how to get to a system with 2 unknowns. Pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

If it's an identity in $x$, there must be an $a,b$ such that it is true for all $x$. So just try values of 2 values of $x$, solve for $a,b$ and plug back to check if it is indeed an identity

You should get $a = 2 , b = 3$

**EDIT**

In your solution, once you take the common denominator on the left side, you get a fraction, whose numerator must be a constant. That means the coffecient of $x$ in the numerator must be $0$, and the constant would be $b$ - that's how you proceed

Answer (score 0):

The left hand sides are equal, and the denominator on the right is the same, hence the numerator on the right must be the same. That is

$$b=3ax+a-6x+1$$

$$b=(3a-6)x+(a+1)$$

Hence we must have $3a-6=0$, I will leave the rest to you.